# Multiple calls to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have an API that either (1) runs a loop and adds 1 to a variable initialized at 0 every second, and returns the variable after 3 seconds; or (2) uses setInterval() to add 1 every second and then setTimeout() after 3 seconds to return the variable (after 3 seconds). If I run the API twice in sequence, is the first method more inefficient since it'll take 6 seconds to finish running both calls, while the latter will just take 3? What are the benefits of doing it in the (1) way?

Answer (score 1):

First approach **blocks your code** execution. **Forget it as a nightmare!**
There are no benefits doing it that way.

Node.js environment is **asynchronous**, so stick to it's async nature as much as possible.

And yes, please paste some code. *Things may vary depending of your actual problem.*